# Non-static field from static content with public string arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm currently going through some tutorials on Java and Android and have just moved onto arrays.  I'm trying to modify an application I made earlier to use arrays rather than strings in the code.

I have my main class called FunFactsActivity, and in that I am declaring a String array called mFunFactsActivity.  I am then loading the string array into mFunFactsActivity - this works fine.

I then have an onClickListener on a button, and when pressed will get a new fact from my FactBook class.  My code is as follows:

**FunFactsActivity.java**

```
public class FunFactsActivity extends Activity {

    private FactBook mFactBook = new FactBook();
    public String[] mFunFactsActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);

        Resources resources = getResources();
        mFunFactsActivity = resources.getStringArray(R.array.funFacts);

        final TextView factLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextView);
        final Button showFactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showFactButton);
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fact = mFactBook.getFact();
                factLabel.setText(fact);

                int color = mColorWheel.getColor();
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
                showFactButton.setTextColor(color);
            }
        };
        showFactButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

What I am then trying to achieve is to access the mFunFactActivity array in my FactBook.java file to use it to get a random fact as per below:

**FactBook.java**

```
public class FactBook {

    public String[] mFunFactsFactBook = FunFactsActivity.mFunFactsActivity;

    public String getFact() {

        String fact = "";
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();  //Construct a new Random number generator
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mFunFactsFactBook.length);

        fact = mFunFactsFactBook[randomNumber];

        return fact;
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is with the line:

```
public String[] mFunFactsFactBook = FunFactsActivity.mFunFactsActivity;
```

I am being told that I cannot reference a non-static field from static content.  My knowledge of 'static' isn't great at the moment and I am 100% sure I understand it, however from what I can tell, none of the code I have written states that mFunFactsActivity is static.

Answer (score 2):

you can't access a not static member as if it were static. The difference it that the not-static member is linked to the object instance, so you will get a different member for each new operator, while if it is maked as static you will get just one. What you can do is create method inside FactBook to init the array of facts. For instance:

```
public class FactBook {

public String[] mFunFactsFactBook = null;

public void initFacts(Context context) {
      if (mFunFactsFactBook == null) {
           Resources resources = context.getResources();
           mFunFactsFactBook = resources.getStringArray(R.array.funFacts);
      }
}

public String getFact() {

    String fact = "";
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();  //Construct a new Random number generator
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mFunFactsFactBook.length);

    fact = mFunFactsFactBook[randomNumber];

    return fact;
}
```

}

and call `mFactBook.initFacts()` inside onCreate(). You still need a valid context

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, using mFactBook.initFacts(getApplicationContext()); however my only issue is that I am not repeating the same code in both the FunFactsActivity and FactBook

Answer (score 1):

When you write "FunFactsActivity." you are referring to the class and not an instance of the class. That's a static context. You could access it if you had an instance of FunFactsActivity on the left-hand side of the dot, like so:

```
... = someFunFactsActivity.mFunFactsActivity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of `FunFactsActivity` to access the instance field `mFunFactsActivity`. Your choices are make the field static (only one in your application),

```
public static String[] mFunFactsActivity; // <-- in FunFactsActivity
```

Or, use an instance - something like,

```
 public String[] mFunFactsFactBook = new FunFactsActivity().mFunFactsActivity;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me as I was given nullPointer issues.  Perhaps there was something additional I was supposed to do that I'm not aware of?